# Ruby DevKit on Windows 8, still can't install native extension

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows8-64bit. My Ruby installation is in `C:\Ruby193` and the Devkit is in `C:\DevKit`

I followed the DevKit installation and it's a success.

Then the guide asks me to test it by running `gem install json --platform=ruby` which returns this error (looks similar as before having DevKit installed):

**Note**: This other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698952/cannot-install-ruby-devkit-on-windows-8) told me to add the `DevKit` installation folder to Environment `PATH`, I did it but still got same error.

```
C:\Users\myname>gem install json --platform=ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381:0,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:41:8: error: redefinition of 'struc
t timespec'
In file included from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../.
./../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:12:0,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:62,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/sys/types.h:89:8: note: originally defined here
In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1381:0,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:48:8: error: redefinition of 'struc
t timezone'
In file included from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/win32.h:63:0,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/defines.h:223,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
                 from c:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/time.h:260:8: note: originally defined here
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
```

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: You should mark your own answer as "correct", as that will lower the chance someone else tries to answer for you. The question and answer may still prove useful to someone else in same situation as you, we all make mistakes.

Comment: Yeah I will accept it when I'm allowed to... in 2 days. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I used the wrong DevKit.

For Ruby 1.9.3 and below, we should use `DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe` The `mingw` is for 2.0 and above.

It works great now.